# Is returning multiple results an antipattern?

Tags: ruby, anti-patterns

I have a strong feeling against methods returning multiple results for further multiple assignment, like this:

```
class ImportUsersFromFile
  def perform 
    ...
    [imported_rows, errors]
  end
end
```

because it introduces an obscure and inobvious data structure "an array, first element of which is this thing and the second is that other thing". It would be fine if it was obvious that the method should return such structure. For example, it's okay to expect three values `first_name, middle_name, last_name` from a method like `Person#name_parts`.

But I can't back my opinion with anything but my words. Is multiple result considered an anti-pattern or code smell of some kind? Would love to have some links.

Comment: Your code returns an array which can put into multiple values using the Destructuring feature of Ruby. What's wrong with an array?  

BTW: Why not raising errors instead of put them into the return values?

Comment: I explained what is wrong with destructuring the array in this case: the interface is not clear. One thing is to expect that `perform` returns list of imported users, and other thing is to know that it really returns an array of two lists. Errors are not raised in my case, because they are not exceptional -- if there are errors in some rows, other rows should be imported anyway.

Comment: Then your method interface returns two buckets, one with the good rows and one with the bad. It sound reasonable to me but not like an antipattern. If the error cases doesn't matter then ignore them explicitly like `users, _ = importer.perform`.

Comment: Is getting back 4 columns from an SQL query in an array an anti-pattern?  No, but the code would smell if you made 4 trips to the db just to get them to satisfy the one-return-variable-per-function-call.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I'm not sure I would call this an antipattern. I do take your point, but for the fact that Ruby specifically has its interpreter deal with the very issue you talk about:

```
def foo
  [1,2]
end

a = foo    # -> a = [1,2]
a,b = foo  # -> a = 1, b = 2
_,b = foo  # -> b = 2
```

So as far as I'm concerned, having to know that the method/function returns two values is no worse than having to know that you *pass it* two values.

Having said that: if it makes you uncomforatable, you should certainly avoid doing it yourself.  There is nothing wrong with that.

Comment: My problem can't be illustrated with `foo`'s and `bar`'s. It's more about semantics. As I said, I find perfectly valid a method `Person#name_parts` that returns an array of three values, order of which is evident from the name, but not so much an imperative method that executes some batch actions and returns numbers of successes and failures. Incoming parameters (their names and order) can be seen in the signature of the method. But to know the order of returned values, one needs to read the method's code. That's is not a convenient interface for me.

Comment: @Hnatt In Ruby your interface is idiomatic I guess. If it feels wrong to you or the users of your code then feel free to change it. Alternatives are custom _Value objects_ or named values implemented by a Ruby `Hash`.

Comment: @Hnatt, forgive me. But if your problem can't be illustrated with generic, example code ("foos and bars") _and_ it's a problem of semantics, then I'm personally unsure whether it's a programming problem at all.  Isn't it idiomatic that semantic programming problems **can** be illustrated with example code?  Again: how is having to know the order of the returned values any different from having to know the order of the input parameters?

Comment: @AndyJones you see the order of input parameters in method signature, which can be shown in your IDE as you type the method name. For returned value you have to either read the method body or add some documentation to it. But I agree with you that my question most like does not belong on StackOverflow. Thanks for trying to help -- I shoud've started with this, not with ranting about your example code.

Comment: @Hnatt -- I don't use an IDE. That's a good point about the method signature turning up in it.